# Is there any Negative Impact on increasing semaphore count?

Tags: spring-boot, semaphore, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

What is the negative impact on increasing semaphore count while implementing HystixObservable command.
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests = 1000?

we are using netflix hystrix for fault tolerance in our application and we need to provide semaphore count in order to avoid "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not acquire a semaphore for execution"

Default count of semaphore is 10 and we increased to 1000 and application is working as expected but I wanted to see if there is any negative impact if we increase the semaphore ?

execution:
        isolation:
          semaphore:
            maxConcurrentRequests : 1000

Comment: Good question. I am fighting the issue too and I have seen, that to many RuntimeExceptions may open the circuit.